# ASP.NET reading data from DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

new problem out there. While reading data from database and when it runs out of records, it simply says "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present", so the question is how to prevent that?

Here's my code:

```
{
    Label3.Text = Request.QueryString["Username"];

}

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JEVGENIJ-PC;Initial Catalog=ViaFitness;Integrated Security=True");
static SqlDataReader dr;
SqlCommand cmd;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Summary where UserName='"+Label3.Text+ "'", con);

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    Label3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
    Label1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
    Label2.Text = dr[0].ToString();

}
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dr.Read();
    Label3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
    Label1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
    Label2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    con.Close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

call dr.read before every fetch.  check if it is true , which means data is present

MSDN [SqlDataReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) Method - Advances the SqlDataReader to the next record.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

// Call Read before accessing data. 
while (reader.Read())
{
        ReadSingleRow((IDataRecord)reader);
}

// Call Close when done reading.
reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure you have data in your reader:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Summary where UserName='"+Label3.Text+ "'", con);

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Label3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
        Label1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        Label2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    }

}
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Label3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
        Label1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        Label2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Check out the MSDN-page for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Datareader Read() method returns bool value. If it returns true, it succsesfully read next record, if it returns false - it is not read record because there is no more.
So you should test result of Read method and then try to access to its values.

Answer (score 0):

`Read()` jumps to the next record. Is there nothing you cant' acces this. Try this for only one record

```
If(dr.Read()) {
    Label3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
    Label1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
    Label2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
}
```

or this for all

```
While(dr.Read())) {
    ' do something
}
```